# how to replace with whitespace?

Tags: sed, newlines

For reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993781). I wanted to replace a period and whitespace (e.g. `.\t` or `.\n`) with the period plus a linebreak plus the whitespace (i.e.  change the example strings to `.\n\t` or `.\n\n`, resp.).

*Can this be done efficiently in bash/Linux?*

(I know basic sed, but not enough to handle patterns like this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grouping in GNU `sed`

```
sed -E 's/\.(\s)/.\n\1/g' file
```

Grouping `()` is used when we want to use part of the matched regex later.

Groups will be ordered and you can refer to them by it's number for example here we have `\1`

- `-E` to enable extended regex to avoid escaping `(` and `)`

Answer (score 4):

`sed`:

```
sed -E 's/\.([[:space:]]|$)/.\
\1/g'
```

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/\.(\s|$)/.\n\1/g'
```